# coldfusion 10 - hiding statuscode when custom handling

Tags: error-handling, http-headers, coldfusion-10, iis-8, cfwheels

I've set `Enable HTTP status codes` to off

And I'm using cfWheels to handle the errors, and call the status codes 
`<cfheader statuscode="404" statustext="HTTP 404 - Page does not exist" />`

but I keep getting two messages. One generated by the server, and one that I've created.

If I remove the custom header 404 statuscode, I get a 200 code, which is misleading. If I leave it there a `500 - Internal Server Error` gets shown before the html code, so it messes up the layout, and gives the wrong arror code.

I'm only seeing this on a CF 10 server, Not on CF 9.

Comment: I also have the `CGI.PATH_INFO` displayed to show which page generated the error, which seems to be working on CF9 but is empty in cf10 after the 404 age redirect

Comment: _"which seems to be working on CF9 but is empty in cf10"_ - it's probably working on CF10, where they've fixed the bug with IIS where it was *incorrectly* adding script_name to path_info. Though you haven't actually specified if you are using IIS (or any of numerous other web servers) which might potentially be a factor in why you're getting a 500 error. Also, you've not confirmed if this is the exact same code or if it might be a unknown code difference - a [self-contained code example](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the issue would help with that.

Comment: What happens if you change `statustext` to `Not Found`? Clients will sometimes get confused unless you use those exact words.

Comment: The server is using IIS8, CF10, TomCat. My local environment is IIS7, CF9, jRun

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the below code:-

```
<cfcontent reset="true">
<cfheader statuscode="404" statustext="Not Found">
404 page is working as expected. Current time <cfoutput>#now()#</cfoutput>
<cfheader name="Content-Length" value="#getPageContext().getCFOutput().getBuffer().size()#">
```

Also, see if your issue is related to https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3488063

Comment: that worked to the point that the errors match now, but I'm still getting it twice. It may be something IIS is generating

Comment: Check the IIS logs or you can enable Failed Request Tracing in IIS for error codes and then check.

Answer (score 0):

```
<system.webServer>
   <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
</system.webServer>
```

thanks to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cfwheels/lRi_p8QJVYI/mi-5MX_OMYEJ

works, but now returns NOTHING on 404